# Unable to deploy contract that uses Oraclize using Remix

Tags: contract-development, remix, testrpc, oracles

I was trying to use Oraclize just for testing. I was facing problems deploying a sample contract from [quick-start section of oraclize doc.](https://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-quick-start) 
I tried to use both testrpc and private network for deployment of smart contract.

On connecting remix to testrpc and deploying contract, I was hit by an error stating:

```
creation of browser/ExampleContract.sol:ExampleContract errored: Error: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 1000000000000000000000000000001934427 and the senders account only has: 99999999999990327865
at runCall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:69347:10)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:11327:24
at replenish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:8420:17)
at iterateeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:8405:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:8380:16
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:11332:13
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:64434:16
at replenish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:64381:25)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:64390:9
at eachLimit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:64314:36)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:65494:16
at VM.AsyncEventEmitter.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/build/cli.node.js:64085:3)
```

So ideally saying the upfront cost of deploying this contract is **1000000000000000000 ethers**.

Now when I tried connecting this to my private network and tried the same, I was git by an error stating:

```
creation of browser/ExampleContract.sol:ExampleContract errored: Gas required exceeds limit: 2002192.  An important gas estimation might also be the sign of a problem in the contract code. Please check loops and be sure you did not sent value to a non payable function (that's also the reason of strong gas estimation).
```

In both cases, the gas estimate too high preventing me from deploying contract.
I also tried to deploy the same contract using Ethereum-Wallet connected to my private network. But this time instead of importing `oraclizeAPI.sol`, I pasted it's code above my code (AFAIK, there is no way to import contracts files in ethereum-wallet yet).But here also I was hit by `Intrinsic gas too low error`.

PS: I have successfully deployed the same contract on Ropsten using MEW. Also I was able to deploy same contract using truffle and testrpc. So what's the problem with remix.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the javascript VM and was not getting any error or message. But the

```
--callback
```

method was never getting called.
I found this answer [Why isnt Oraclize working?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24026/why-isnt-oraclize-working/24180) which kind of indicatest hat JS VM with Oraclize may not work from the browser Remix. So you can use the Oraclize Remix IDE at https://dapps.oraclize.it/browser-solidity/ and get your code tested end to end. I am yet to try out that IDE, will update if I am able to run my code there.

Comment: Just an update which I forgot earlier. Yup Oraclize works perfectly from its own Remix IDE.