# Urgent help setting up ethereum bridge

Tags: blockchain, truffle, oracles, testrpc-to-ropsten

I've currently download nodejs truffle, testrpc etc etc to set up my development environment. All I need to do is demonstrate the oracle service working. I've found that I need to 'set up an ethereum bridge' [through this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11383/oracle-oraclize-it-with-truffle-and-testrpc). But all it says is to "set it up" which is proving to be easier said than done for me at least.  I'm not the most experienced with these things so every time I try to via PowerShell I'm unsuccessful. Here's what appears when I simply type in "npm install" when in the directory of the git I've cloned.

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!

> sha3@1.2.0 install C:\Users\User\desktop\ethereum-bridge\node_modules\sha3
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\User\desktop\ethereum-bridge\node_modules\sha3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:170:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\desktop\ethereum-bridge\node_modules\sha3
gyp ERR! node -v v9.6.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sha3@1.2.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sha3@1.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-06T16_12_56_237Z-debug.log
```

If anyone could provide a **foolproof explicit tutorial** of how to properly download this thing so I could at least get started, I'd be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 2):

That error can be confusing, one of the dependencies 'sha3' requires python to be installed

> gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

It doesn't say but you need to install python version **2.7**.

Since you are on windows make sure to also install the required c++ compiler. Follow instruction from the installation windows section https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp#installation so you install the correct version.

Comment: Hi ! thanks for answering, did what described but it still doesn't work and now comes up with:

PS C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ethereum-bridge> npm install
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0. I'll try to do my best with it!


C:\Users\Me\Desktop\ethereum-bridge\node_modules\sha3\build\sha3.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported
project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, a
nd that the file exists on disk.

Comment: Did you install the C++ compiler as indicated in the node-gyp documentation? Which version of node/npm are you using? Which version of windows are your working with? If you have a more complete log you can edit your question to add the log.